# How to pass ruby variables between .html.slim files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, slim, actionmailer

I have email template in which I keep and use ruby variables:

```
### mailer/_body.html.slim

ruby:
  start_day_number = @absence.starts_on.strftime('%d').to_i.ordinalize
  end_day_number = @absence.ends_on.strftime('%d').to_i.ordinalize
  start_date = @absence.starts_on.strftime('#{start_day_number} of %B (%A)')
  end_date = @absence.ends_on.strftime('#{end_day_number} of %B (%A)')
  type = @absence.type.capitalize
  status = @absence.status.capitalize

p class="details"
  | Starts: <b>#{start_date}</b><br />
  | Ends: <b>#{end_date}</b><br />
  | Type: <b>#{type}</b><br />
  | Status: <b>#{status}<b><br />
```

Is there any more convenient and readable way to store these variables in another .slim file and pass them to the template?

Optimally, I'd like to have them stored in layouts directory like that:

```
### layouts/mailer.html.slim

doctype html
html
  head
    meta charset="utf-8"
    css:
      ...
  body
    ruby:
      start_date = @absence.starts_on.strftime('#{start_day_number} of %B (%A)')
      end_date = @absence.ends_on.strftime('#{end_day_number} of %B (%A)')
      ...
    == yield
```

..but it didn't work though.

Comment: This feels like an XY problem. Why would you want to define a global variable across all views? Is `@absence` *always* defined, in every single page of your application?!

Comment: If you really do genuinely want those variables to be defined in every view (which I think is extremely unlikely), you could set a `before_action` in `ApplicationController` and set them all there, **as instance variables**.

Comment: Or, perhaps what you should really be looking at is introducing a `Presenter`/`Decorator` pattern into your code. Suppose you were able to just call methods like: `@absence.start_day_number`, `@absence.end_day_number`, etc -- would that be cleaner? For example, you could take a look at the [`draper`](https://github.com/drapergem/draper) library and consider creating a `AbsenceDecorator` class with such methods.

Comment: You are absolutely right, I forgot that I define them globally there. Mailers are the only place where I actually use them, so I wouldn't like to pollute controllers/models with it.

Comment: I was also thinking about creating a partial, say `_locales`, where I put those and rendering it in `_body` partial, but I couldn't make it work..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decorator pattern turned out to be exactly what I needed. Thanks Tom Lord!